# Does scalar multiplication of a matrix change its eigenvalues/singular values

Tags: linear-algebra

If Av=λv then cAv=cλv. If we group the right side like (cλ)v, then a scalar multiplication does change the eigenvalue. Now for the singular value, we need to find the eigenvalues of $(cA)^{T}(cA) = c^{2}A^{T}A$ because c is just a scalar. Then the eigenvalues of cA are $c^{2}λ$ so the singular values are just $cλ$. Is that correct?

Comment: Watch out for the signs with the singular values: by construction, they should always be positive.

Comment: "If we group the right side like $(cλ)v$, then a scalar multiplication does change the eigenvalue." Why so? It is multiplied by $c$ as you have just demonstrated.

Comment: I'm just saying that if the eigenvalue of A is λ, then the eigenvalue of cA is cλ

Comment: If $c\ne1$ you **do** change the eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. If you multiply a matrix by a constant then the eigenvalues are multiplied by a constant but you need an absolute value $|c|$ or in the complex case it'd be $\sqrt{c\cdot c^{*}}$